# How can I output a new text file every time my program runs?

Tags: java

I would like to know how I can make the program output a new text file every time it runs. For example first run machineslot(1).txt, second run machineslot(2).txt, and so forth. Or, make the output file contain when the file was made.

```
File file = new File("MachineSlot.Txt"); 

    try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));) {

        for (int i = 0; i < winData.length; i++){ 

            if (winData[i][0] != 0.0) {

            out.printf("You won Machine %.0f. You won $%.2f. You have %.0f quarters which equals $%.2f %n", winData[i][0], winData[i][1], winData[i][2], winData[i][3]);

            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < plays.length; k++)
            out.println("You were able to play machine " + (k + 1) +" a total of "+ plays[k] + " times.");
    }//end of try.      

    catch(IOException error){
        System.out.println("Could not use the IO file");
    }//End catch
```

Comment: Why do you need PrintWriter for that ?

Comment: And do you also want to write a different file if the loop run again ? Or append in the existing file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution to this is use file name and add timestamp to it.

```
File file = new File("MachineSlot_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
```

Typically speaking any two files generated  will have different time stamp of file generation. Avoid multiple check of existing files.

Other addition is have a formatted date.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss_SS");
File file = new File("MachineSlot_" + formatter.format(new Date()) + ".txt");
```

Comment: Great this should be the solution. According to what Jerry06 has written it has a complexity. Let's say there are 100 file so the loop will run 100 times to generate the new file

Comment: Yeah this works all the time and you will notice this gets used so many times when we generate logs/files repeatedly.

Comment: And the worst part of the @Jerry06 solution is time complexity will keep on increasing every time they generate a new file

Answer (score 1):

You can try this before the `PrintWriter` code

```
File file;
int i = 0;
do{
    file = new File(String.format("MachineSlot(%d).Txt", i++));
}
while (file.exists());
```

Comment: what this is doing is it is adding a number to the file name. It keeps incrementing no being appended to the file name till you get a file with number which does not exist.

Comment: @Jerry06 don't you think it has the time complexity if the file exist ?

Comment: yes, this will have the problem with that, but this will fit with the requirement that number increased (1,2,3,4..). The other solution we can store this number somewhere but will make complex

Comment: I think stacking/storing the number is nice add to it. even though it has added complexity but in the scenario you can easily remember the file name

Answer (score 0):

According to Your problem, best way to add date and time with your file name

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMddHHmmssSS").format(new Date());
```

here current date is converted into specific format then file name would be

```
File file = new File("MachineSlot" + date + ".txt");
```

output looks like(file name)-

MachineSlot20171012094424.txt